# Checkbox covers content in editing mode in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

EDIT: Since I got a downvote, I'll provide some more details

I tried following apples guide for multiple selection in `UITableView`. What I've done is basically only:

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

and then:

```
tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
```

Here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html

In their sample-app the label in the `UITableViewCell` get squeezed a bit to the right when entering editing mode.

However, in my app, the check-box gets covered by the default checkbox.

Like this: [image]

What am I supposed to do to get the correct behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of add subviews (labels) on cell

```
//cell.addSubview(aLabel)
```

add labels on cell's contentView

```
cell.contentView.addSubview(aLabel)
```

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, this is it! Damn, it's so easy to do that mistake! Thank you!

Comment: Additionally make sure that all of the cell's subviews' constraints are linked to the contentView and not to the cell itself